# Magento 1.9.2.1 SUPEE-6788 patch - Hunk fail on .htaccess

Tags: magento, patch

I have just applied the supree 6788 patch to our magento 1.9.2.1 installation however when executing

sh PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.2.1_v1-2015-10-26-11-38-41.sh

I get the following : -

```
 15-10-26-11-38-41.sh
    Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
    ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

    patching file .htaccess
    Hunk #1 FAILED at 207.
    1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file .htaccess.rej
    patching file .htaccess.sample
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Block.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Block/Collection.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Variable/Collection.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Variable.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/sql/admin_setup/upgrade-1.6.1.1-1.6.1.2.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Edit/Form.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Block/Grid.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Edit/Form.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Permissions/Variable/Grid.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/BlockController.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/VariableController.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/etc/adminhtml.xml
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Type/File.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Front/Action.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/UnserializeArray.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Setup.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Changeforgotten.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Block/Account/Resetpassword.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Downloadable/Model/Product/Type.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Resource/Attribute/Collection.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/DownloadController.php
    patching file app/code/core/Mage/SalesRule/Model/Resource/Coupon/Collection.php
    patching file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/admin.xml
    patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml
    patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/register.phtml
    patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
    patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
    patching file app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/customer.xml
    patching file app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/customer.xml
    patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout/customer.xml
    patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
    patching file app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml
    patching file cron.php
    The next patch would delete the file dev/tests/functional/.htaccess,
    which does not exist!  Assume -R? [n]
    Apply anyway? [n]
    Skipping patch.
    1 out of 1 hunk ignored
    patching file errors/processor.php
    patching file lib/Unserialize/Parser.php
    patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Arr.php
    patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrKey.php
    patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/ArrValue.php
    patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Bool.php
    patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Dbl.php
    patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Int.php
    patching file lib/Unserialize/Reader/Str.php
    patching file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
    patching file lib/Zend/Xml/Security.php
```

I take it the patch hasn't been applied correctly ?

Comment: yes,  it didn't apply

Comment: Any ideas why it wouldn't ?

Comment: You need to use the .htaccess files from the base installation, probably you edited those

Comment: Ah yes, never thought about that, ive got a multi site running which needed a edited htaccess. Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happens because of edited `.htaccess` files.

1) Make a backup of your .htaccess file

2) Replace your .htaccess file with the data in .htaccess.sample (download the .htaccess.sample file from your stock Magento install if you don't have it)

3) Apply the patch

4) Copy your backup in .htaccess

5) Add the cron.php lines that were added to the htaccess file by the patch.

Comment: Where can I get a uneditited base htaccess file from ? as i dont have the original and the magento download file is now on 1.9.2.2.

Comment: If you don't have the sample one you would have to dwd it from here https://www.magentocommerce.com/download -> release archive. Also I was getting the same error just because when i pasted it there was an extra line break at the end.

Comment: Hello, ive replaced with the base file, but seems there are other issues, dumping the output below

Comment: do you still have the issue? I see that it fails here dev/tests/functional/.htaccess. What is that path? Also make sure that all previous patches were applied: https://www.magereport.com/scan/

Comment: ive uploaded the dev folder as it didnt appear to be on my server, and then successfully applied the patch. However no products now show on my home page, so need to find out a fix for that now lol 

interesting in the dashboard it doesnt show 1.9.2.2, do i still need to upgrade via connect manager?

Comment: It shouldn't show 1.9.2.2 because you applied only the patches

Answer (score 5):

Using .htaccess.sample will not work. In the stock magento install, `.htaccess` and `.htaccess.sample` are different sizes. 
You will need to use the stock magento `.htaccess` for your version. Once you have the stock version uploaded you can apply the patch and then just add the files tag from the bottom of `.htaccess` to your version of `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 3):

Its very Simple

Step 1: Backup your `.htaccess` and `.htaccess.sample`

Step 2: Upload Original `.htaccess` and `.htaccess.sample` files as per your Magento version.

Step 3: Execute patch

Answer (score 1):

add then cron stuff manually to your htaccess and remove that stuff from patch batch.

Answer (score 0):

May be this help

Try to delete the this folder **/lib/Unserialize** then apply.